# Grails/Hibernate: how to order by isnull(property) to get NULLs last?

Tags: hibernate, grails, null, criteria

Normally when ordering ascending by a field, you get the NULL values first, and then the more interesting values. Often, you want NULL values last. In MySQL, you can do this with:

`SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY ISNULL(name), name;`

However, I'm using Grails with Hibernate criteria, and I have absolutely no idea how to do this there. Is this even supported in any way? Is there some way to order by a custom SQL expression? I'd hate to rewrite all my criteria to plain SQL just to get it to sort correctly.

Comment: Looks like the Hibernate 'bug' has been fixed, https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-465. I would love to see updated answers for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hibernate you can try with this below code :

Criteria c = ...;

c.addOrder(Order.asc("name").nulls(NullPrecedence.LAST));

Comment: same can be done for grails criteria too.. def userCriteria = User.createCriteria() userCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc(FIRST_NAME).nulls(NullPrecedence.LAST));

Answer (score 5):

if you want to order and  **HibernateCriteriaBuilder** to set *NullPrecedence* in ***GORM***   the **AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder** provies you with the method [order()](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/latest/api/org/grails/orm/hibernate/query/AbstractHibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#order(org.hibernate.criterion.Order)) that you can set a **org.hibernate.criterion.Order** like regular Hibernate

Example

```
     People.createCriteria().list (){
          order(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.asc('name')
                . nulls(org.hibernate.NullPrecedence.LAST)
           )
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's not even in Hibernate yet: there's an [open bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2381) for this.

Though, one could use `NativeSQLOrder` from that bug comments and try to inject a proper function into `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`. You only need to add a `sqlOrder` method to `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` class, doing approximately same as `HibernateCriteriaBuilder.order()`.