# In sort closure, how to get null value last?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

Hello I am using Grails 2.1 and I have a little problem I can't find a good solution to. I am querying the database for some objects and it returns and sort it as expected with one exception, the null value is first.

Here is the code I may use to query the database:

```
Object.findAllByObjectTypeAndDateBetween(ObjectType.REGULAR, startDate, stopDate).sort {it.str}
```

Is there any way I can sort by the strings and getting all null values last instead of first? I am looking for a simple way, not like this:
[Grails/Hibernate: how to order by isnull(property) to get NULLs last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787855/grails-hibernate-how-to-order-by-isnullproperty-to-get-nulls-last)

Thanks.

Comment: if you want sort from database check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34685962/2561990)

Comment: if you want to sort data from database check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34685962/2561990)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this:

```
objects.sort { a, b ->
  !a.str ? !b.str ? 0 : 1 : !b.str ? -1 : a.str <=> b.str
}
```

Expanded for explanation:

```
objects.sort { a, b ->
  if( !a.str ) {             // If a.str is null or empty
    if( !b.str ) {           // If b.str is null or empty 
      return 0               // They are the same
    }
    else {                   // a.str is empty or null, but b.str has value
      return 1               // b.str should come before a.str
    }
  else {                     // a.str has value
    if( !b.str ) {           // b.str is null or empty
      return -1              // b.str should come after a.str
    }
    else {                   // Both have value, 
      return a.str <=> b.str // Compare them 
    }
  }
```

This will put null strings **and** empty strings at the end of the list, and sort the rest alphabetically

If you want the empty strings at the head of the list (and the nulls at the tail), you'd need to explicitly check for null rather than relying on Groovy Truth:

```
objects.sort { a, b ->
  a.str == null ? b.str == null ? 0 : 1 : b.str == null ? -1 : a.str <=> b.str
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, you're as helpful as always :)

Comment: unfortunately I got an exception saying it can't compare the values. `Cannot compare project.Str with value 'Avalue' and project.Str with value 'Anothervalue'`, using the first solution. I want all empty stuff at the back. However, there will just be 1 null value and no empty strings.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you also explain the logic behind the first one?

Comment: @cubsink is `it.str` a String? If not, is it a comparable class?

Comment: Actually it's an object reference I think, my bad. So it might be `it.str.name` but that would generate an error for when just sorting `it.str` before. To be clear, it is an object that belongsTo the parent with one field called "name" which is a string.

Comment: `Cannot get property 'name' on null object'` is what I always get. It's strange because if I sort by `it.str` (or something else) in this case it gives me back `selection: 'name'`

Comment: @cubsink Added explanation by expanding the ternary operators.  Try:  `it.str?.name` using the null-reference operator

Comment: yes thanks for that, now it works but the null values seems to get stuck in the middle. I think I have to test some things first. I will come back with an answer in some seconds..

Comment: @cubsink Try the latest version, I made a mistake and missed out one half of the ternary :-/

Comment: yeah it works flawlessly. Thanks for this and for the explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use:

```
Object.findAllByObjectTypeAndDateBetween(ObjectType.REGULAR, startDate, stopDate).sort{a, b-> null == a || null == b ? 1 : a <=> b }
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution does not even iterate over the correct value I'm afraid. I think you are missing the .str

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NullComparator class:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.comparators.NullComparator

objects.sort { a, b ->
    new NullComparator(true).compare(a.str, b.str)
}
```